# How to show/hide a MarkerCluster in google maps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I need to have different markers for different `mapType`s, and I'm pushing them to a [MarkerClusterer](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#MarkerClusterer).

I "hide" the markers with:

```
cluster.set("map", null);
cluster.resetViewport();
cluster.redraw();
```

And "show" them with:

```
cluster.set("map", MAP);
cluster.resetViewport();
cluster.redraw();
```

The problem is that MarkerClusterer seems to not like `set("map", null)`; it throws the error `TypeError: Object #<a MarkerClusterer> has no method 'remove'`. How can I show/hide them the proper way?

Comment: The setVisible() answer from this other question seems to work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894384/how-to-hide-and-show-markerclusterer-in-google-maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fought my way into solving this by a little monkeypatching and a little hack. I'm still waiting for a clean answer, but this *is* a solution to my problem, so I'm also posting this:

```
MarkerClusterer.prototype.remove = function () {}

[..]

cluster.set("map", HIDDEN_MAP); // remove the clusterer
cluster.resetViewport();
cluster.redraw();
```

Comment: Where do you declare 'HIDDEN_MAP' ? Or is it a non-existing variable so you might as well pass 'null' ?

Comment: @Micros this is (was) a separate map that was never shown. Anyway, this is an old question and I don't even have that code anymore, probably the API changed very much since then. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

In the Javascript API v3 it is sufficient to say:

```
clusterer.setMap(null);
```

If you set your map back to the existing map object, the clusters will reappear.

```
clusterer.setMap( this.map );
```

Also, I would suggest not to name your Clusterer 'cluster', like in your example. The MarkerClusterer contains Cluster objects, which are the actual clustered markers and not the ClusterER itself.

Answer (score 6):

Elegant way to clear the cluster

```
cluster.clearMarkers();
```

Comment: Can you clarify ?  Are you referring to adding an extension because clearMarkers does not exist on the MarkerClusterer object.

Comment: @mikecamimo Are you using API v3? Then look at the [documentation](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html)

Comment: clearMarkers() doesn't just remove them from the map, it removes them from the clusterer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more complete solution:

in .html add:

```
<div id="map-canvas-hidden" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="map-canvas-shown" style="width:500px; height:500px"></div>
```

in .js add:

```
MarkerClusterer.prototype.remove = function() { };
var HIDDEN_MAP = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas-hidden"), {});
var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas-shown"), {});
```

to show the clusters:

```
    cluster.setMap(gmap);
    cluster.resetViewport();
    cluster.redraw();
```

to hide the clusters:

```
    cluster.setMap(HIDDEN_MAP);
    cluster.resetViewport();
    cluster.redraw();
```

finally, I needed the folowing patches to markerclusterer.js:

```
--- markerclusterer.js.orig 2013-12-06 18:02:32.887516000 +0100
+++ markerclusterer.js  2013-12-06 18:03:25.487516924 +0100
@@ -620,6 +620,7 @@
  */
 MarkerClusterer.prototype.getExtendedBounds = function(bounds) {
   var projection = this.getProjection();
+  if (!projection) return null;

   // Turn the bounds into latlng.
   var tr = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
@@ -657,7 +658,7 @@
  * @private
  */
 MarkerClusterer.prototype.isMarkerInBounds_ = function(marker, bounds) {
-  return bounds.contains(marker.getPosition());
+  return bounds ? bounds.contains(marker.getPosition()) : false;
 };
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code to easily show/hide clusters on the map (updated for the current versions of Maps API and JS-Cluster-Renderer). Thanks Gabi.

```
MarkerClusterer.prototype.remove = function() {};

MarkerClusterer.prototype.hide = function() {
  this.setMap(null);
  this.resetViewport();
};

MarkerClusterer.prototype.show = function() {
  this.setMap(map); // replace map with your reference to the map object
  this.redraw();
};

// To hide the clusters:
cluster.hide();

// To show the clusters:
cluster.show();
```