# How to hide and show MarkerClusterer in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, show-hide, markerclusterer

i'm trying to hide/show markerClusterer when user clicks some buttons:

Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mappa"),mapOptions);
    var marker_tmp = [];
    var markers_tmp = [];
    $.each(json,function(index,value){
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat,value.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latLng});
        if((value.candidato in markers_tmp)==false){
            markers_tmp[value.name]=[];
        }
        markers_tmp[value.name].push(marker);
    });
    for(var name in markers_tmp){
        markers[name]= new MarkerClusterer(map,markers_tmp[name]);
    }
```

I create multiple markerClusterer each one is associated to a particular name.

So i have some buttons associated to these particular name and i need to hide/show the marker clusterer associated with that button.

```
/*This is the function associated to a button when it is clicked*/
function hide_show_cluster(name,visible){
    var tmp_cluster = markers[name];
    //call a function of markerClusterer (tmp_cluster) to hide/show it
}
```

I've done lots of tests but no one satisfy my request.
Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: You need to hide/show the markers with some categorie or you need to 'unclusterer' it?

Comment: i just need to hide/show the cluster with the categorie clicked by the button associated with it

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've been struggling the whole morning with this but fortunately I got to a solution.

First of all, make sure you have the latest MarkerClustererPlus version https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer

then it is very easy,

When creating the markers make sure you

> set its visible flag to false.

And when creating the marker clusterer do it this way:

```
new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, { ignoreHidden: true });
```

if you want to show the clusterer just do this:

```
for (var it in markers) {
    markers[it].setVisible(true);
}

markerCluster.repaint();
```

to hide the cluster:

```
for (var it in markers) {
    markers[it].setVisible(false);
}

markerCluster.repaint();
```

Hope it helps, regards

Comment: just fyi... in the most current version 1.2.0 of MarkerClusterer the parameter is called: 'ignoreHiddenMarkers'

Comment: it works BUT cluster number counters don't update, so the map is a bit confusing.

Comment: Adding this line:   for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) { if(  markers[i].visible == false ) count--; }   in the markerclusterer.js after line 359 do the trick

Comment: this won't work, you need to loop through the ´markers_´ array inside the ´markerCluster´ and set each visibility to false.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same case and this is how I do it... hope it helps

> cluster instanciate

```
let markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
```

> to hide the clusters:

```
function hideMarkers() {
    for (let i in markers) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markerCluster.clearMarkers();
}
```

> to show the clusters:

```
function showMarkers() {
    for (let i in markers) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
    markerCluster.addMarkers(markers);
}
```

here is a jsfiddle link to test http://jsfiddle.net/3s6qfzcy/

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example:

1. Define the click handlers for the buttons;
2. Using the function getMarkers() to get all the markers and save the results to a variable (var allMarkers = getMarkers());
3. Create another variable to add/remove markers (var currentMarkers = allMarkers);
4. When you click in each button you can loop the currentMarkers variable and  use the functions removeMarker(MARKER_TO_REMOVE) or addMarker(MARKER_TO_ADD, true) (the true is to redraw the map);
5. When you are looping the markers you can access their information (do a console.log(marker) to see what I'm talking about);

For more information you could see the documentation here: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html

Comment: i like your solution... i create a global associative array: every key is a categorie and every value is the array of marker. So on button click i do:                                                    function showMaps(name,visible){
 var tmp_cluster = clustersContainer[name];
 if(visible){
     tmp_cluster.addMarkers(map,globalMarkers[name],true);
 }else{
  tmp_cluster.removeMarkers(map,globalMarkers[name],true);
 }                                                                but unfortunately it doesn't want to show it..